# Tomcat - how to get http 500 instead of 404 when application wasn't deployed correctly?

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, http-status-codes

We have several REST applications using Spring MVC. Time to time some application after deploy don’t start. When our Javascript client tries access resource url, it gets 404 status code. Therefore it assumes, that resource doesn’t exist. More appropriate for us would be http status 500 returned in Tomcat response. Is possible change this default Tomcat behavior?

I've found similar problem with JBoss (uses embedded Tomcat) but no answer:
https://serverfault.com/questions/367986/mod-jk-fails-to-detect-error-state-because-jboss-gives-404-not-500

Comment: wouldn't it be more helpful to determine the source of your deployment failure rather than trying to change the status code the user sees?

Answer (score 0):

## HTTP proxy

If you have some sort of a proxy in front of your Tomcat server (like [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) or [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx)), I believe it can be configured to translate 404 into a different status code and error page. If you don't have any proxy or want the solution to remain self-contained:

## Custom Spring loader and servlet filter

Since you are using Spring, I guess you are bootstrapping it using [`ContextLoaderListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html) in `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This class is responsible for bootstrapping Spring and this is the step that in most cases causes the application startup to fail. Simply extend that class and swallow any exception so it never reaches the servlet container, hence Tomcat won't think your application deployment failed:

```
public class FailSafeLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FailSafeLoaderListener.class);

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        try {
            super.contextInitialized(event);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("", e);
            event.getServletContext().setAttribute("deployException", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Code is pretty simple - if Spring initialization fails, log the exception and store it globally in the `ServletContext`. The new loader must replace the old one in `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.blogspot.nurkiewicz.download.FailSafeLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Now all you have to do is to read that attribute from servlet context in a global filter and reject all requests if application failed to start Spring:

```
public class FailSafeFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Exception deployException = (Exception) request.getServletContext().getAttribute("deployException");
        if (deployException == null) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(500, deployException.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Map this filter to all requests (or maybe only controllers?):

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>failSafeFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The solution might not be exactly what you want, but I am giving you a general, working example.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but we would like to resolve it in Tomcat level, but I don't know if it is possible... For example Jetty returns 503 on such errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with some change.

What we do :

- write a servlet that do something like:

  ```
  if (req.getContextPath().isEmpty()){
      resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
  } else {
      resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
  }
  ```
- put jar containing this class into tomcat lib.
- change conf/web.xml to add the servlet and map it to `*.404`
- set global error `404` to `/404.404`.

  ```
  <error-page>
      <error-code>404</error-code>
      <location>/404.404</location>
  </error-page>
  ```

your servlet will be called both with root application and with all deployed application.